# 連用形 of 「だ」 - difference between 「だっ」「で」「に」

Tags: grammar, conjugations, renyōkei, auxiliaries

Out of the conjugations of だ, the 連用形 is what is confusing me.

I understand だ、だろ、な、なら fine, but I'm confused about だっ、で、に.

I think my question might be a bit too broad and that's because I really have no clue what I'm supposed to figure out. I might have some understanding of those uses when I see them in a sentence, but grouped in isolation like that, I'm perplexed.

Could someone explain how they're used or what they mean?

Comment: 断定の助動詞「だ」の活用に、「に」ってあったっけ・・・？

Comment: 『日本文法大辞典』によると、「形容動詞を認めない立場に立てば、連用形に「に」の形が加えられる。」(p.412)

Answer (score 1):

Well, だった is simply the past tense form of だ.

きれい**だった**。
It **was** pretty.

で can get a little bit more complicated when you start to describe all the cases it can be used, but it's basically just the TE-form of だ. So, if you wanted to combine two sentences, for example "I went to the store" and "I bought some food", it would become "スーパーへ行って、食べ物を買いました。" You put the verb 行く into TE-form, and add on the next sentence. So, if your first sentence ended with だ, you would do the same thing.

僕は学生**で**、数学を勉強しています。
I **am** a student, **and** I am studying math.

Also, the negative form of だ technically uses the TE-form as well.

で+は+ない　＝＞　ではない　＝＞　じゃない

Or is also used in the word である. Which is basically another way of saying だ, but that's another topic for another time.

As for に I think you're referring to something like きれいに　or 静かに where these words would normally be followed by な, correct?
You can think of this as simply turning the adjective into an adverb.

これは**静かな**部屋ですね。
This **is** a **quiet** room.

この部屋では**静かに**して下さい。
Please **be quiet** in this room.

Comment: "`it's basically just the TE-form of だ.`" "`turning the adjective into an adverb`" Thanks. These helped me understand the connection between 連用形 and adverbial forms better. In my answer to a [question](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/45276/do-the-adverbial-forms-of-verbs-and-nouns-exist) about the adverbial forms of verbs and nouns the て-form of verbs and -に added to adjectival nouns came up.

Comment: Also, in the question: "Could someone explain how they're used or **what they mean**?" could be answered with the actual meaning of the Japanese word. It's used for linking/connecting (but what to where generally speaking?) and all the different forms are just how the grammar works for different parts of speech it occurs after if I understand it correctly. This answer works without such generalization as well, though, and the question did say "or".

Comment: Specifically defining だ and it's forms can be a little hard as it's kind of vague. It's usually described as the copula  meaning "to be", but the definition in the Japanese dictionary is <<助動>>[体言（相当の表現）に付く]話し手・書き手がその事柄を（肯定的に）認めて述べるという態度を表明する。

Comment: I mean 連用形's meaning since all the uses connect either だ or the word it's used with to the following word. But I agree that it's vague. In snailplane's comment on the question there is a quote from a book saying that に as the 連用形 of だ exists only if you don't acknowledge adjectival nouns

Comment: I've just come across this site which has some pretty good information on the topic I think.             https://nanapi.com/ja/84610

Comment: Nice find. It just find it odd that 『ただし、連用形には「に」がありません』 when they basically have the same function. Also the examples about で were really good

Comment: Yeah I guess it's just saying that に is used with 連体形 when だ is being used as 形容動詞 but not in its regular 連用形 form. I'll say, I've never really used the Japanese terms when studying grammar so it's a little hard to keep all the classifications straight.

Comment: I know many of these terms but no common logic behind them because I took an unorthodox approach to learning Japanese. I never really studied any grammar, but I'm equipped with a j-e dictionary and I run all the text I read through MeCab with the [UniDic](https://osdn.net/projects/unidic/) dictionary to get dictionary forms and part of speech + conjugation tagging. I find it interesting to connect the dots now that I mostly understand what's being said and how words work together. (btw UniDic is far more accurate than what jisho.org uses)

Comment: This is pretty good as well. http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/. Also, 岩波 prints a good series of J>E, E>J, and J>J dictionaries.